# JComboBox events - Swing

Tags: java, swing, events, jcombobox

How to make sure that the Item is changed in `JCombobox` from User, not from another method?

Because I have method that change the item as well. But the events must do something when the user has changed the item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best idea is to mark your own event with a boolean flag, as it proposed by @LucA. But if for some reasons you cannot do it, you can try to check the originator of the event. If the originator is you combobox - the event was triggered by user. Here is an example:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.ComboPopup;

/**
 * <code>JComboText</code>.
 */
public class JComboText {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] items = new String[] {"First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"};
        JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>(items);
        combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                boolean byUser = isTriggeredByUser(combo);
                System.out.println("Changed by: " + (byUser ? "user" : "program"));
            }
        });
        JButton button = new JButton("Clear selection");
        button.addActionListener(e -> combo.setSelectedItem(null));
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Combo test");
        frm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frm.add(combo);
        frm.add(button);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static boolean isTriggeredByUser(JComboBox<?> combo) {
        // check whether the change was triggered by another component
        final ComboPopup popup = (ComboPopup) combo.getUI().getAccessibleChild(combo, 0);
        final JList<?> list = popup.getList();
        if (EventQueue.getCurrentEvent() instanceof InputEvent) {
            return Objects.equals(EventQueue.getCurrentEvent().getSource(), combo)
                    || Objects.equals(EventQueue.getCurrentEvent().getSource(), list);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can copy the method `isTriggeredByUser` and use it in your program.

Comment: it works, Thank you so much for your help it is much appreciated!!

Comment: @Fadi When my suggestion solved your problems, please mark it as helpful (click the grey checkbox left to my answer). In this case we get some points of reputation ;)

Answer (score 3):

This may work :

Declare a boolean, meaning "the combobox is being changed by the program, not the user"

Make it true everytime your code changes the selected value, and false again just after.

In your actionPerformed event, do nothing if your boolean is true. If it is false, that means the user is changing it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!